# Sync between chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

do you know any way how to synchronize DATA from chrome extensions between 2 computers? (Windows and Ubuntu) 
I know there is option to synchronize bookmarks and extensions (it works), but DATA from these extensions wasn't transferred.
For example: I use 'Calendar and Countdown' extension, I would like to have my dates also in Ubuntu, I would rather not add all these dates again :( 
(Extension was add to my second computer but without inside data). 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That service would have to be provided by the extension itself, i.e. you'd sign into the extension on your Windows machine with an account, and then sign into the same account but on your Ubuntu machine.